# Product not found - in app purchase (sandbox)

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I had done with all the process of in app purchase but i got empty array in response.

I have followed the steps 
1. created  AppId and provisioning profile in developer.apple.com
2. created new app in my itunesconnect.apple.com  and also added product id
 in my viewcontroller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
      SKProductsRequest *_request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.hexa.InAppPurchaseDemo1.product4"]];
        _request.delegate = self;

        [_request start];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Serpentine" message:@"Error: Could not connect to store. Try enabling in-app-purchases in settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products; // got empty array

    if (products.count != 0) 
    {
        _product = products[0];
    }
    else
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Serpentine" message:@"Error: Could not connect to store" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];//this line of code runs a second after the controller opens
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you fill the Contract, tax and banking section in you iTunesConnect account? Did you add the products to your app in iTunesConnect?

Comment: you can check the answer, might be helpful for you. stackoverflow.com/a/42065967/3770366

Comment: @ Adolfo , i did all the things. and  i need help in sandbox inApp purchase

Comment: sandbox need tex agreement?